# How to avoid executing commands as root using phpseclib's library?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

Currently I'm executing all commands as root, which is a very bad idea and unsafe as I read. I want to execute the commands in a secure way.

An example of currently using command:

```
use \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
   
// connect function using root user...

function ssh_connect(){
$connect = new SSH2('localhost', '22');
        if (!$connect->login('root', 'pass')) {
            throw new \Exception('Login failed');
        }
return $connect;
}

// execute function

function ssh_exec($cmd){
        $ssh = ssh_connect();
        $stream = $ssh->exec($cmd);
        return $stream;
    }
```

So I call it like

```
ssh_exec("mkdir -p /home/username/test; cp -r /home/test/*.jpg");
```

I read that it will be more secure if I'm using sudo... but how can I make an user-group which can

1. Allow to copy files from only specified folders
2. Disallow to go outside from their folders
3. Using screen command, useradd/userdel command but restrict making/deleting users in this group which I want to add

And they can make/delete files and folders only under their homes right?

Or there is any other&easier way to achieve these but still secure?

Comment: You should _never_ do such things from your scripts... it potentially opens a whole bunch of exploiting options. Just don't do it... don't expose your backend to your frontend in such a way.. really, it's bad and dangerous

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asked these. I want to do it in a secure way...

Comment: Find a different way... this problem is not solved via a script, use offline tools designated for the purpose. This is about backend access, eg. administrative work.. shouldn't be in the web at all.

Comment: Thanks for useful answers. How about making a shell script which is seperated by args, so if the arg is "mkdir" then executing `mkdir -p $2`? Let's say the script named as test.sh -> `./test.sh mkdir /home/benyo/test` so you can't execute nothing but mkdir.

Comment: There is a `mkdir()`function in PHP, why would you want to use the shell for creating a directory? Again, please think about the implication here... the webserver/php user runs isolated and has certain rights, well defined, but you open a loophole to act as a _different_ user through the script, and that's where shit hits the fan. If you need a shell script to run, consider a cron... but don't allow the user to influence the contents of that shellscript through your PHP script - that will allow injection of system commands, which is by far worse than SQL injection can be

Comment: It's not about the `mkdir` function. I need to exec more commands which you need to connect to an ssh, that is just an example...

Comment: Ok, then mind my comments about poluting your shellscript with unsolicited user input and that you don't want that.

Comment: I feel like this question might be better posted on superuser.com or some such as it's more about Linux permissions than it is about a programming task..